# Is it possible for an Azure Function App in C# to execute a command line application?

Tags: c#, azure, command-line, azure-functions, file-storage

I'm looking to create a Function App in C# with a timer trigger which will occasionally (e.g. once per day) manipulate our Salesforce environment. Specific tasks may (will) include:

1. (Re)setting trace flags for Users and Apex Classes.
2. Downloading the debug logs so they can be persisted (and searched).

I'm hoping to do this without reinventing too many wheels.
As Sfdx Cli should be able to do these tasks from the command line, I'm wondering whether/how I can manipulate Sfdx from an Azure C# scheduled function app.

- How can I make Sfdx available to whatever "serverless" server is hosting the Function App?
- How can I tell the Function App where to find it on this server?
- How can I tell the Function App to do something with it by providing some command, including arguments, as might be provided through a command line?
- How can I capture any response(s) which may be provided as console/terminal output, that these response can be parsed?
- When I use Sfdx Cli to download logs from Salesforce, how can I either store them somewhere (perhaps on blob storage instead of local file storage) or intercept them so the application might do something with the data?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is dockerize the function and then deploy it.

This will help you to run the console app in the function.

Also, you will get all the desired functionality of the function while the dockerization will help you run console app on it.

You have to bundle the console app with the function app.
refer the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image?tabs=in-process%2Cbash%2Cazure-cli&pivots=programming-language-javascript#enable-continuous-deployment-to-azure) on deploying using docker.

Comment: Docker seems like something which will overcomplicate what I am trying to do.  Is that the only option for making some external command line tool available to C# in a Function App context?

Comment: Azure function is serverless technology you don't have access to the underlying infrastructure . So by dockerizing it we can controll the image thus we can add console apps , .exe executables , etc.